# How to validate both lowercase and uppercase input?

Tags: c#, uppercase, lowercase, string-function

I have a winform application and I was wondering what is the c# code to validate both lowercase and uppercase input for string search comparison.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the method in the `string` class `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` before validation.

Something like

```
string inputString = "inputfoo";

if (inputString.ToUpper() == "INPUTFOO"){
  //do something, this is going to be executed
}
```

you can also check `ToLower()`, `ToLowerInvariant`, and `ToUpperInvariant` methods for further choices.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness Ian.